# Transitivity in one sided statistical test

Tags: t-test, hypothesis-testing

Let's consider 3 samples sets of equal size A,B,C coming from the random variables a,b,c and any consistent hypothesis testing method.

If we use A,B to test $H_0: \mu_b - \mu_a = 0\,\,\,\,H_1: \mu_b - \mu_a > 0$ and obtained $p$-value $< 0.5$

And if we use B,C to test $H_0: \mu_c - \mu_b = 0\,\,\,\,H_1: \mu_c - \mu_b > 0$ and we obtained $p$-value $< 0.5$

Can we conclude that using A,C to test $H_0: \mu_c - \mu_a = 0\,\,\,\,H_1: \mu_c - \mu_a > 0$ we will obtain $p$-value $< 0.5$

This is easy to prove with the $t$-test (because $p$-value $< 0.5$ for the first test implies that sum(B)-sum(A) > 0 and so on ...) But can we generalize this to other hypothesis testing methods ?  (for example Wilcoxon)

Comment: The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test is famously non-transitive, simply because for independent random variables $A$, $B$, & $C$, $\Pr(B>A) > \frac{1}{2}$ & $\Pr(C>B)>\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't imply $\Pr(C>A) >\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Indeed I believe there are a few examples already in posts on site

Comment: thanks for the answer